# How we can column header in renderTable not in renderDataTable in R shiny? I want to group of few columns in my renderTable?

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying in this way:

```
myContainer <- htmltools::withTags(table(
   class = '',style="width:100%",
   thead(
     tr(
       th(colspan = 2, 'Group 1', class = "dt-center"),
       th(colspan = 2, 'Group 2', class = "dt-center")

       ),
     tr(
       lapply(names(data.frame(df)), th)
     )
   )
 ))
```

#UI:

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
      htmlOutput("TextTable")
  )
```

My rendertable in server:

```
output$TextTable <- renderTable({
    varsub
  }, width = "100%", include.colnames = TRUE,
  sanitize.text.function = identity, spacing = 's',
  container = myContainer,
  columnDefs = list(list(className = "dt-center", targets = "_all"))
  )
```

But this is not working, any help would be appreciated. Or please suggest any other way to do it.
[image]

Comment: Hi Aninjay. I'm not understanding what you're trying to do - specifically, I see no reference in your ui code to `TextTable`.

Comment: @Phil please find the expected output.